# Cómo relaciono 2 tablas con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, moongose

Cómo relacionar **2 tablas** en **nodejs** usando **express**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los siguientes **modelos:**

**profesores.js**

```
    //Require Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var tablaProfesores = new Schema({
    id:number,
    dni:string,
    nombre:string,
    apel1:string,
    apel2:string,
    stdio_max:string
});
```

**asignaturas.js**

```
   //Require Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var talaAsignaturas = new Schema({

    id:number,
    nombre:string,
    id_profesor:number,
    duracion_por_clase:number
});
```

**¿Cómo puedo hacer la relación de 1:n entre id_profesor y el id?**

Comment: La relación es nivel de mongo que es tu bd y no devexpress o nodejs

Comment: Recuerda que MongoDB no es una base de datos relacional, por lo tanto el concepto de ***relación*** no existe. Lo que tu deseas hacer se llama ***referencia***. Debes establecer una referencia en tu esquema de *asignaturas* a documentos del tipo *profesores*. Eso de acuerdo a tu imagen y el campo que has resaltado. Dices que quieres una *relación* 1 a muchos. ¿Es que una misma asignatura puede ser impartida por muchos profesores? O ¿la relación es al revés? ¿Podrías aclarar eso? Saludos

Comment: Buenas, me refiero a que un profesor puede dar muchas materias. Pero una materia solo por un profesor de modo que en la tabla asignatura seria **UNIQUE** un registro con 'id asignatura' + 'id profesor que la imparte' de ese modo solo una persona puede dar esa determinada asignatura pero a su vez el mismo profesor puede dar varias de las mismas, pero siempre siendo el unico que la imparte. No se si me explico. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que deseas realizar lo puedes hacer usando una referencia a tu colección *profesor* en tu colección *asignatura*.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea establecer una *relación* 1:n entre 2 colecciones de MongoDB, usando Mongoose como ODM. El campo `id_profesor` en la colección *asignaturas* se desea relacionar con el campo `id` en la colección *profesor*. La relación es tal que 1 asignatura puede tener *n* profesores.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que te propones voy a darte algunas pautas o sugerencias sobre cómo escribir tus modelos

1. No uses `id`'s hardcodeados, te sugiero que uses siempre el campo `_id` autogenerado por MongoDB para cada documento en una colección. Esto es realmente útil para evitar el tener que crear validadores tipo *unique*.
2. No uses como nombre de tu esquema la palabra *tabla*. Aunque puedes usarlo, lo ideal es que te acostumbres a llamar las cosas por su nombre representativo. En MongoDB no existen las tablas, existen las colecciones. Un esquema no es una tabla, tal vez se parezca por el hecho de tener *campos* que traducidos podrían considerarse *columnas*. Pero es que en realidad las colecciones en MongoDB son cosas bastante diferentes (y a la vez parecidas) a las tablas en una base de datos relacional. La conclusión aqui es: "llama a las cosas por su nombre".
3. Estudia todas las posibilidades que te ofrece Mongoose al asignar los tipos a un campo. En la [documentación de Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) puedes encontrar cuáles son los tipos permitidos en un Schema. Se les conoce como SchemaTypes. Entre los que allí se mencionan se encuentra: `Array`, y es ese tipo el que nos permitirá realizar la *relación* (realmente el término es referencia, pero se puede usar tranquilamente el término *relación*).

Aclarados esos puntos, te describo cómo vas a realizar la referencia.

Normalmente, yo uso nombres bien sugerentes en mis archivos. Además, suelo programar usando la sintaxis de ES6, aquí usaré ambas y tu decides la que más convenga.

El modelo de *profesor* lo escribiremos en un archivo llamado **profesor.model.js**:

```
// ES6
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
// ES5
// var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// usaremos 'const', ya que el esquema no cambia, por lo tanto 'let' o 'var' no tienen sentido
// otra cosa que normalmente evito es declarar variables que no sean necesarias
// por ejemplo hacer 'var Schema = mongoose.Schema;' no tiene sentido para mi
// me parece un desperdicio de memoria

// para ES5 solo sustituye 'const' por 'var'

const profesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    dni: {
        type: String,
        required: 'El campo DNI es requerido u obligatorio'
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: 'El campo NOMBRE es requerido u obligatorio'
    },
    apel1: {
        type: String,
        required: 'El campo PRIMER APELLIDO es requerido u obligatorio'
    },
    apel2: {
        type: String,
    },
    stdio_max: {
        type: String
    }
});

// ahora ya podemos esportar nuestro modelo que se va a basar en el esquema recién creado
export default mongoose.model('Profesor', profesorSchema);
// ES5:
// module.exports = mongoose.model('Profesor', profesorSchema);
```

Con esto ya tenemos el modelo *profesor*, si lo detallas bien no he incluido el campo `id`. Como te comenté al principio, MongoDB se encarga de asignar un campo `_id` a cada documento que sea creado en la colección *profesores*. Y es éste campo `_id` el que vamos a referenciar en nuestro esquema *asignatura*.

Ahora crearemos el modelo *asignatura*, y lo haremos en un archivo llamado **asignatura.model.js**

```
// ES6
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// ES5:
// var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const asignaturaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: 'El campo NOMBRE es requerido u obligatorio'
    },
    profesores: [{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Profesor'
        }
    }],
    duracion_por_clase: {
        type: Number
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Asignatura', asignaturaSchema);
// ES5:
// module.exports = mongoose.model('Asignatura', asignaturaSchema);
```

Con esto ya tenemos listo el modelo *asignaturas*.

Ahora vamos a explicar lo que estamos haciendo en el campo *profesores*:

1. El campo se llama *profesores* ya que contendrá una lista con todos los `_id` de los profesores que deseemos agregar a la asignatura.
2. El tipo de campo es una `Array` que contiene elementos tipo documento u objeto.
3. Cada elemento de nuestro `Array` tiene un campo llamado *id* cuyo tipo es `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`, y que hace *referencia* al modelo *Profesor*.

Con esto ya tienes una *relación* 1:n de la colección *asignaturas* a la colección *profesores*.

Ahora, ¿cómo uso eso?

Sencillo, usamos el método *[populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)* de Mongoose.

Una forma de implementarlo sería la siguiente:

```
//Supongamos que accedemos a las asignaturas usando el siguiente endpoint: /api/asignaturas
import Asignatura from './asignatura.model';
// ES5:
// var Asignatura = require('./asignatura.model');

app.get('/api/asignaturas', (req, res, next) => {
    Asignatura.find((err, asignaturas) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: 'Error de servidor: ' + err.message
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json(asignaturas);
    })
    .populate('profesores', 'nombre apel1 apel2');
});
```

Con esto, al requerir la lista de asignaturas, el método *populate* traerá además del campo `_id`, los campos `nombre`, `apel1` y `apel2`.

Espero que esto sea lo que estabas buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que a nivel relacionar seria una relacion n a n ( un profesor puede tener mas de una asginatura y una asignatura puede ser impuesta por mas de un profesor ), de todas formas yo agregaria un array en la tabla profesor haciendo referencia al id de asignatura. asi creo que no deberias tener problemas

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var tablaProfesores = new Schema({
   id:number,
   dni:string,
   nombre:string,
   apel1:string,
   apel2:string,
   stdio_max:string,
   id_asignatura:[type: number]

});
```

Comment: Seguro que el tipo de relacion que indicas es la que corresponde a tu descripción? el tipo de relación al que haces referencia es `1:n`

Comment: Esto tampoco es eficiente a nivel del tipo de referencias que se manejan en MongoDB. La idea de las referencia o documentos referenciados es optimizar las búsquedas. Mongoose es un ODM que ayuda mucho debido a que propone esquemas como un molde para, valga la redundancia, modelar documentos. Si se desea conocer el nombre o apellido del profesor, usando esta solución se necesita una segunda consulta a la BD. Para eso es que se usan las referencias.